# error en consulta COUNT(*) la paginacion se pierde

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Tengo un problema con una consulta:

```
       `Mi bd.       
       Tabla.profesión
       id_pofesion, profesión`


       `Tabla.clientes
        id_clientes, cedula, nombres, apellidos, id_profesion
```

resulta que tengo un buscador el cual ejecuta su acción con los registros que se muestra en mi tabla, mi problema es, si aplico esta consulta se muestra perfectamente con la paginación.

```
`$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clientes;";`
```

pero como tengo que mostrar la profesión del cliente que se muestra en el campos id_profesion no puedo mostrar el numero si no el nombre de la profesion del cliente, pero con esta consulta se me muestra perfectamente, pero la paginación se queda en la página 1 osea solamente se me muestra el numero 1 de la paginación y no puede ser porque el limite de fila por paginas es 3 y hay mas de tres registros en la base de datos osea se pierde la paginación.

```
 $query = "SELECT
 clientes.id_clientes,
 clientes.cedula,
 clientes.nombres,
 clientes.apellidos,
 clientes.id_profesion,
 profesion.id_profesion,
 profesion.profesion
 FROM clientes INNER JOIN profesion ON 
 clientes.id_profesion=profesion.id_profesion ORDER BY clientes.id_clientes;";
```

mi duda es como puedo hacer un COUNT(*) con mi consulta n°2 para no tener problemas con mi paginacion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No vas mal encaminado, simplemente junta las dos consultas.

```
$query = "SELECT
count(clientes.id_clientes),
clientes.id_clientes,
clientes.cedula,
clientes.nombres,
clientes.apellidos,
clientes.id_profesion,
profesion.id_profesion,
profesion.profesion
FROM clientes INNER JOIN profesion ON 
clientes.id_profesion=profesion.id_profesion ORDER BY clientes.id_clientes;";
```

La consulta te devolverá en primer lugar el recuento y posteriormente los datos.

Hay una pregunta similar en SO en inglés que puede ayudarte [Select count and other records in one single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872225/select-count-and-other-records-in-one-single-query).

Comment: gmarsi me sirvió tu ejemplo solo debes corregir is_clientes por id_clientes en tu consulta, pero a lo demás en fin gracias 1000% funcional